# Custom options on simple products fail to show on order

Tags: magento

I have simple products which have several custom options.  The option process seems to work fine on the front end.  The options selected show up in the shopping cart and the price is correct.  I place the order and when I pull it up in admin the options headers are shown but the actual selection is not. The selections are shown in the order confirmation email sent to me and the customer.  So they must be getting into the admin.  any ideas as to why they are not on the order or invoice?

Comment: What version of Magento are you running?

Comment: Try reindex product flat data.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that didn't help

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this in 1.6.1.0 by modifying the file

> /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Items/Column/Name.php

I copied this file from 1.7.0 which doesn't have this problem.
And here is the explanation:

In the class declaration there was no methods at all, the one we need is getFormattedOption
If you find this function defined in this file, then skip this answer.

If not, simply insert this function inside the class, so the entire file must be like this:

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Items_Column_Name extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Items_Column_Default
        {
            /**
             * Add line breaks and truncate value
             *
             * @param string $value
             * @return array
             */
            public function getFormattedOption($value)
            {
                $_remainder = '';
                $value = Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($value, 55, '', $_remainder);
                $result = array(
                    'value' => nl2br($value),
                    'remainder' => nl2br($_remainder)
                );

                return $result;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. There's a bug (even up to 1.6.2) that is in an adminhtml template file. Here's the fix.

```
diff --git a/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml b/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
index 7b36ee1..9e1f603 100644
--- a/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
+++ b/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
@@ -41,16 +41,7 @@
             <?php if (isset($_option['custom_view']) && $_option['custom_view']): ?>
                 <?php echo $this->getCustomizedOptionValue($_option); ?>
             <?php else: ?>
-                <?php $_option = $this->getFormattedOption($_option['value']); ?>
-                <?php echo $_option['value']; ?><?php if (isset($_option['remainder']) && $_option['remainder']): ?><span id="<?php echo $_dots = 'dots' . uniqid()?>"> ...</span><span id="<?php echo $_id = 'id' . uniqid()?>"><?php echo $_option['remainder'] ?></span>
-                    <script type="text/javascript">
-                    $('<?php echo $_id ?>').hide();
-                    $('<?php echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?php echo $_id ?>').show();});
-                    $('<?php echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?php echo $_dots?>').hide();});
-                    $('<?php echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?php echo $_id ?>').hide();});
-                    $('<?php echo $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?php echo $_dots ?>').show();});
-                    </script>
-                <?php endif; ?>
+                <?php echo $_option['value']; ?>
             <?php endif; ?>
             </dd>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this works for me in 1.6.2.0. C.E.

1. open this file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
2. Add the following line between two endif; statements on lines 53 and 55 respectively.

   ```
   <?php echo $_option['option_value']; ?>
   ```
3. Refresh the cache types and reload the page. You can see your custom options finally in your order product details on the magento backend / admin panel.